# Boundary modes in scipy.ndimage.laplace

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

The function [scipy.ndimage.laplace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.laplace.html) can be used to calculate the Laplace operator applied to N-dimensional arrays. If one wants to use this function, for example, for applications in physics, the crucial part is often how to handle the boundaries.

Looking at the function documentation, a number of options are supported:

- ‘reflect’ (d c b a | a b c d | d c b a)
- ‘constant’ (k k k k | a b c d | k k k k)
- ‘nearest’ (a a a a | a b c d | d d d d)
- ‘mirror’ (d c b | a b c d | c b a)
- ‘wrap’ (a b c d | a b c d | a b c d)

One thing I am personally missing is a **'smooth continuation'** option. In the above notation, it would correspond to a slightly modified version of the mirror option:

- 'smooth continuation' ((a-d) (a-c) (a-b) | a b c d | (d-c) (d-b) (d-a))

The motivation for this is to not introduce kinks at the boundary, which all of the supported options seem to be doing for an arbitrary input.

**Question: Is there any way to do this Laplace operation in scipy/numpy?**

Answer (score 1):

I digged a bit into scipy source code.
What I found makes me think it won’t be easy to add your custom mode using only python scypi/numpy : you would end up re-coding most of all the backbone code of scipy in python.

The mode you are referring to is managed deep down into the underlying scipy’s C code.
You will need to change a C enum value, update the source file accordingly with your custom mode logics, and produce a new package.

That might be an issue/evolution to open on github: either allow a custom build array method, or implement new modes. Or 1 ticket for each.

See [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/8dba340293fe20e62e173bdf2c10ae208286692f/scipy/ndimage/src/ni_support.c). Quoting :

```
/* Extend a line in memory to implement boundary conditions: */
int NI_ExtendLine(double *buffer, npy_intp line_length,
                  npy_intp size_before, npy_intp size_after,
                  NI_ExtendMode extend_mode, double extend_value)
{
    double *first = buffer + size_before;
    double *last = first + line_length;
    double *src, *dst, val;

    switch (extend_mode) {
        /* aaaaaaaa|abcd|dddddddd */
        case NI_EXTEND_NEAREST:
            src = first;
            dst = buffer;
            val = *src;
            while (size_before--) {
                *dst++ = val;
            }
            src = last - 1;
            dst = last;
            val = *src;
            while (size_after--) {
                *dst++ = val;
            }
            break;
        /* abcdabcd|abcd|abcdabcd */
        case NI_EXTEND_WRAP:
            src = last - 1;
            dst = first - 1;
            while (size_before--) {
                *dst-- = *src--;
            }
            src = first;
            dst = last;
            while (size_after--) {
                *dst++ = *src++;
            }
            break;
        /* abcddcba|abcd|dcbaabcd */
        case NI_EXTEND_REFLECT:
            src = first;
            dst = first - 1;
            while (size_before && src < last) {
                *dst-- = *src++;
                --size_before;
            }
            src = last - 1;
            while (size_before--) {
                *dst-- = *src--;
            }
            src = last - 1;
            dst = last;
            while (size_after && src >= first) {
                *dst++ = *src--;
                --size_after;
            }
            src = first;
            while (size_after--) {
                *dst++ = *src++;
            }
            break;
        /* cbabcdcb|abcd|cbabcdcb */
        case NI_EXTEND_MIRROR:
            src = first + 1;
            dst = first - 1;
            while (size_before && src < last) {
                *dst-- = *src++;
                --size_before;
            }
            src = last - 2;
            while (size_before--) {
                *dst-- = *src--;
            }
            src = last - 2;
            dst = last;
            while (size_after && src >= first) {
                *dst++ = *src--;
                --size_after;
            }
            src = first + 1;
            while (size_after--) {
                *dst++ = *src++;
            }
            break;
        /* kkkkkkkk|abcd]kkkkkkkk */
        case NI_EXTEND_CONSTANT:
            val = extend_value;
            dst = buffer;
            while (size_before--) {
                *dst++ = val;
            }
            dst = last;
            while (size_after--) {
                *dst++ = val;
            }
            break;
        default:
            PyErr_Format(PyExc_RuntimeError,
                         "mode %d not supported", extend_mode);
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

*Please note that I’m absolutely no expert in scipy, so maybe I’m missing something huge, or there are very documented reasons that explain what are the proposed modes.*

---

EDIT 2019-Ap-24 some [documentation here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8465)
I don't get all the details, but from what I understand:

- It refers to academic work of Dr. Philippe Thevenez as potential source for some part of algorithms.
- The ticket seems to indicate that some other modes may be developed in the future.

[This ticket](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4075) also deals with new modes.

Given the open dates of tickets, it may take some time before it comes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this is extremely helpful! A "this will be hard" answer with very productive suggestions like yours can be more useful than a "do this" answer sometimes. I have upvoted for now and will award the bounty before it expires, but I will wait with the accept tick in case someone else comes along.

Comment: Your welcome. I want to believe that there are some theoretical/academic reasons behind the default modes, but this is far from my direct understanding. Image/signal processing experts might have clues, or maybe ask on github ?